# Doing simple Ajax call - ajax URL not outputting anything

Tags: module, magento-1, controllers, ajax

app/etc/modules/Custom_Customajax.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Custom_Customajax>
             <active>true</active>
             <codePool>local</codePool>
        </Custom_Customajax>
    </modules>
</config>
```

app/code/local/Custom/Customajax/controllers/AjaxController.php

```
<?php
class Custom_Customajax_AjaxController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action {

    public function indexAction() {
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->renderLayout();
    }
}
```

app/code/local/Custom/Customajax/etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Custom_Customajax>
      <version>0.1.0</version>
    </Custom_Customajax>
  </modules>
  <frontend>
    <routers>
      <Customajax>
        <use>standard</use>
        <args>
          <module>Custom_Customajax</module>
          <frontName>customajax</frontName>
        </args>
      </Customajax>
    </routers>
    <layout>
      <updates>
        <customajax>
          <file>customajax.xml</file>
        </customajax>
      </updates>
    </layout>
  </frontend>
</config>
```

mytemplate/layout/customajax.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="1.0">
  <customajax_ajax_index>
    <block type="customajax/customajax" name="root" output="toHtml" template="customajax/customajax.phtml" />
  </customajax_ajax_index>
</layout>
```

mytemplate/template/customajax/customajax.phtml

```
<?php

echo 'test';
```

Ajax call

```
$('.submit-form').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/mysite/customajax/ajax/index",
        type: "POST",
        success: function(data) {
            if(data.success) {
                $('#results').html(data.message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.** Change your module's router configuration like this.

```
       <routers>
          <customajax>
            <use>standard</use>
            <args>
              <module>Custom_Customajax</module>
              <frontName>customajax</frontName>
            </args>
          </customajax>
       </routers>
```

Note the change that you made here is using `customajax` instead of `Customajax`. Now Magento will recognize your `customajax_ajax_index` layout handle.

**2.** Make sure your custom block exist. As per the definition in your layout XML file, Magento needs the following block class to be defined inside your module.

FILE : `app\code\local\Custom/Customajax/Block/Customajax.php`

```
<?php
class Custom_Customajax_Block_Customajax extends Mage_Core_Block_Template
{
}
```

Job is not over. Eventhough we defined our custom block, Magento do not know where exactly it needs to look for our custom block. So we need to tell to Magento that, "she" should look in our own module. For this add this code snippet in `config.xml`

```
<global>
    <blocks>
        <custom_customajax>
            <class>Custom_Customajax_Block</class>
        </custom_customajax>
    </blocks>
</global>
```

**3.** I am not sure about this point. You need to set `url` keyword like this

```
    url: "www.domain.com/customajax/ajax/index",
```

where `www.domain.com` is your site's base url.

You are done. Now clear the cache and then try again

Comment: About point 3./ you should consider using $this->getUrl( as said in http://stackoverflow.com/a/8836722/2375207

Comment: @nicolallias yes. I totally agree. But if he is using an external js file, then `$this->getUrl()` won't help.